# git runner is unable to access

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to set up a gitlab runner to use gitlab-ci instead of my Jenkins.
I set up a docker container with linked docker.sock

```
   docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /config/file/on/host:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

After the container run I registered a new runner to gitlab server that ends in following configuration

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "lianli"
  url = "<https://gitlab_server.de"
  token = "<secret>"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "debian:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

So now everything is connect. But when the pipeline is running it ends in an access error:

```
remote: Git access over HTTP is not allowed
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab_server.de/group/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
stages:
 - test

variables:
 NGINX: nginx:stable-alpine

before_script:
  - docker info

test:
 stage: test
 script:
   - docker build -t nginx_test .
```

I do not understand, why it could not access?

Note: The runner is Version 9.3.0 and gitlab is version 9.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your GitLab instance configured to accept http requests to repository?
[image]
Are you a member of the project?

Comment: I am so stupid, todelly forgot that I set it to only ssh...
But now I have a new error:
Cloning into '/builds/group/project'...
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly